# Time-dependent Sobolev spaces

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, real-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Given the Sobolev space $H^1((a,b);H^2(\mathbb{R}))$ and a function $g$ in that space. Consider now another function $f \in C_c^{\infty}((a,b) \times \mathbb{R}).$ Then
for almost any $t \in (a,b)$ we have $g(t)f(t) \in H^2(\mathbb{R}).$ Now, the Laplacian on $\mathbb{R}$ maps $H^2$ into $L^2$, thus we can apply it
$\Delta ( f(t)g(t)) \in L^2(\mathbb{R}).$

We can also first differentiate the product $\frac{d}{dt}(f(\cdot)g(\cdot)) \in L^2((a,b); H^2(\mathbb{R}))$ Then this is pointwise also a.e. in $H^2(\mathbb{R})$ and can then apply the Laplacian, i.e. $\Delta \left( \frac{d}{dt}(f(t)g(t))\right) \in L^2(\mathbb{R}).$

So far nothing but the definition.

But:  Is it true that $t \mapsto \Delta(f(t)g(t)) \in H^1((a,b); L^2(\mathbb{R}))$ and is it then true that $\frac{d}{dt}\left(\Delta(f(t)g(t)) \right) = \Delta \left( \frac{d}{dt} (f(t)g(t))\right)$ for a.e. $t$?

Comment: Have you tried to establish the claim for $g \in C_c^\infty(a,b) \otimes C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ and then to show that everything is continuous w.r.t. the $H^1(a,b;H^2(\mathbb{R}))$ norm?

Comment: thanks, that seem to work indeed. but this space is probably not correct, as $C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ is not in $H^2$ and $C_c^{\infty}(a,b)$ not necessarily dense in $H^1(a,b)$, but I suppose $C^{\infty}(a,b) \otimes C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}) \cap H^1((a,b);H^2(\mathbb{R}))$ is perfectly fine.

Comment: My bad, but good to hear :)

Comment: This boils down to a key property of the Bochner integral: If $T \colon X \to Y$ is a bounded operator, and $f$ is Bochner-integrable, then $Tf$ is Bochner-integrable and the integral operator commutes with $T$, i.e. $$\int_X Tf\,\mathrm d\mu = T \int_X f\,d\mu$$